# How to require fields if a certain radio button is checked with jQuery Validate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the code below with the [jQuery Validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate) plug-in, however I'm receiving the following error after clicking outside of one of the fields that should be required when "Canada" is checked. Any ideas?

```
province: {
    depends: function(element) {
        return $("input[name='country'][value='ca']").is(':checked')
    }
},
```

> $.validator.methods[method] is
>   undefined [Break On This Error]
>   eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(...x5b|trigger|x21|x23'.split('|'),0,{}))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
      $('#checkbox').click(function() {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('#element').rules('add', {
                    //rules
                });
            }
```

When you click on the checkbox to check the result, you can add the rules manually.

Comment: The problem with this is I need to have rules required by default with the pre-selected radio button. Then I would need to remove them somehow if the other button is clicked and vice versa if the buttons are toggled.

Comment: $('#checkbox').rules('remove',{rule(s) to remove); You can choose the rules you want to remove.

Comment: I have a "Search Type" field on a form. As you select from 7 different search types, I remove and add rules to the Search Text field. It works very well once I got the process worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your problem but your missing a semi-colon on this line

```
return $("input[name='country'][value='ca']").is(':checked');
```